# Program does not recognize .modal("show") function after appending HTML to page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, twitter-bootstrap-4, express-handlebars

I am writing a program where a click event handler fires an ajax request to my node server, which then renders info inside of a handlebars partial and sends it back to the client (`res.render("partials/scraped-article", data);`). The client-side javascript appends this html to the document and shows a modal using the bootstrap .modal("show") function. The program shows the modal the first time the click event handler gets fired, but does not recognize the .modal("show") function afterwards. Is there a way to fix this?

Client-Side Javascript:

```
$(document).on("click", "#scrape-options li", function(){
    var choice = $(this).text();
    var request;

    if(choice === "website1")
        request = "/scrape/website1";
    else
        request = "/scrape/website2";

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET", 
        url: request
    }).then(function(response){
        $(".news-article").remove();

        $("footer").append(response);

        $('.news-article-img').each(function(i, element){
            $(this).css({'height': ($(this).next().height() + 'px')});
        });

        $("footer h1").addClass("display-none");
        $("#articles-added").text($(".news-article").length);
        $(".modal").modal("show");
    });
});
```

Comment: what if you hide the modal before showing: $('.modal').modal('hide');

Comment: That still gives me the error $(...).modal is not a function. It seems like Bootstrap functions get disabled after the first time the function runs.

Comment: If you are using jquery.slim you might need the full version of jquery for .modal() to work. (I'm not sure though)

Comment: .modal() works the first time the click event handler fires though.

Comment: If I comment out $("footer").append(response), I no longer have this problem. This has something to do with appending a res.render response to handlebars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that even if you are rendering a partial, the response sent from the server will be embedded in the default template (i.e. it will be a full HTML document). If you simply add this to the DOM, you will be inserting the script for Bootstrap a second time, which will do weird things like disable the $(...).modal function. Instead, you should use the array.split method to extract the body HTML and then append this to the DOM.